# How can I create a transition piece for my custom penny floor to hardwood?

Tags: flooring, epoxy, transition

My fiancé and I did a project of turning our kitchen floor into a penny floor.  Whether we should have or not, we put the floor on top of the previous laminate floor.  This meant a layer of floor board followed by the layer of pennies, finished off with a layer of epoxy.

It is gorgeous and we are in love with it.

However, this additional height caused us to have weird transition heights between our hardwood and the penny floor.  We went to a big box hardware store, got some transitions, and nailed them in.  However, The rock back and fourth and are uneven, causing dirt to collect underneath.

We are unsure what to do here?  We are able to so some wood working, but finish work has always been a struggle.  We've thought about: caulking it and be done, foam, custom transition with a piece of wood from a lumber yard, spending the money for a finish carpenter, just about anything.

I've provided pictures so maybe they can communicate the issue at hand.  The last one is to give you an idea of how the floor sits (if that helps).
[image: Picture of uneven transition]

[image: Picture of uneven transition]

[image: Picture of uneven transition]

[image: Picture of uneven transition]

Comment: Do you have any pictures of the transition between floor surfaces  **without** a trim piece that's not working for you blocking the view of how it comes together?

Comment: What's the height difference between the two floors?

Comment: That's a nice floor  (my two cents).

Comment: So screw those transitions down - as nails always pull loose over time.

Comment: i would remove the strip and add dense black small-gap weather stripping along the wooden-floor edge side of the strip, then re-attach. You might want to play with how far back towards the middle you run the line for best results. It should keep out the dust and hide better than white caulk, which would probably call attention to itself from the wood floor room...

Comment: @Ecnerwal I will try to get this ASAP.  The problem is they were put in with those "screw nails" so pulling them out is an issue.

Comment: @SteveSh The height difference fluctuates some, from about 7/16"-1/2"

Comment: @dandavis I will definitely give this a look.  I will say that one issue is that these transitions already wobble back and fourth because they aren't high enough for the height difference.  So, adding something under would stabilize them, but the front piece would have a slightly bigger gap on the hardwood floor side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a transition profile that has a slight ellipsoid curve:

[image]

This would allow height difference between the two floors to disappear underneath the ellipse, and if you screw them down, both sides will be flush with their respective floors. You'll have to find one that has sufficient space underneath to cater for the height difference though.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite approach, which does require cutting a fairly accurate slot, is a stone threshold that sticks up a bit above both floors. I'm seeing some absurd and some reasonable prices when I search for those, so shop with care.

You cut the slot to suit the threshold you buy, add mortar and insert the stone.

[image: marble threshold between vinyl tile and wood. Image by me.]

Apologies that the vinyl tile is old and still bears the marks of the type of transition you show, which it used to have to carpet. This was done as part of the wood floor project.

Comment: I think this is the way I'd like to go but seems like it might be a little hard for me to do.  I guess that's taking a router to the floor to cut out the groove needed to make that piece fit?  Are these pieces about to be found out in a common big box HW store?

Comment: Done with a handsaw saw and a mallet & chisel, in this case. Pre-scored with a utility knife and a straightedge. They are usually in the "tile" area of a big box that's well-stocked - generally stored end-on to the aisle, so not easy to spot, but if you look them up on the website first you can often get a hint of where, exactly, they are in the store, to limit the hunt.

Comment: Thanks!  I’ll give a look and see about getting this done!  Thanks!